# Rails 3.1 Select All checkbox

Tags: ajax, ruby-on-rails-3

this is my view:

```
 @bulk_objects.each do |bulk_warehouse|
      bulk_error = @wh_errors[:"bulk_warehouse#{@count}"] if @wh_errors      
-%>
<tr class="<%= cycle("odd", "even") %>">
             <%= hidden_field_tag("bulk_warehouse_id#{@count}",bulk_warehouse.id) %>
               <td><%= text_field_tag("bulk_warehouse_asset#{@count}", bulk_warehouse.asset, :disabled => true)%></td>
              <td><%= text_field_tag("bulk_warehouse_serial#{@count}", bulk_warehouse.serial, :disabled => true) %></td>



              <td><%= check_box_tag "enable_record#{@count}",1,false,{:onclick => "bulk_warehouse_asset#{@count}.disabled = 
                                                                                bulk_warehouse_serial#{@count}.disabled = 
                                                                                !this.checked;"}%></td>



                    <td class="last">
                <%= link_to "#{t("web-app-theme.delete", :default => "Delete")}", bulk_warehouse_path(bulk_warehouse), :method => :delete, :confirm => "#{t("web-app-theme.confirm", :default => "Are you sure?")}" %>
              </td>


            </tr>
          </div>          
    <%  @count = @count +1 %>
 <% end -%>
      </table>
       <div class="actions-bar wat-cf">
    <div class="actions">
    </div>
 ..
```

and this is my controller:

```
 @bulk_objects = BulkWarehouse.all
                         @count= @bulk_objects.count
```

Now I would add in my view a "Select all" checkbox that when you click on it enables all other "enable_record#{@count}" checkbox. I know that this thing should be done using Ajax and Jquery but I don't know how. Anyone can help me?
Thank you ll

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use button_to_function to create a button that will check/uncheck all the boxes on the form.

Place this code in your view, where you want your check/uncheck button to go. When the button is clicked, it will run the toggleChecked javascript function.

```
<%= button_to_function "Check / Uncheck All", "toggleChecked()" >
```

Place your javascript code at the bottom of your view.

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
    var toggleChecked = function() { $('input[type="checkbox"]').click(); });
</script>
```

The function also can be put into the respective .js file in assets/javascripts.

That should get you up and running.

### --------------- UPDATE ------------------

Button_to_function is now deprecated. I recommend handling this using an HTML5 button and jQuery.

View code for your button:

```
<button type="button" id="check_all">
    Check / Uncheck All
</button>
```

Javascript:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
    $('#check_all').on("click", function(){ $('input[type="checkbox"]').click(); });
</script>
```

Comment: button_to_function is deprecated now.  What's the next best thing?

Comment: @FletchRichman Thanks for your suggested edit. I don't know why those folks rejected it. I will update the answer accordingly.

Comment: I have searched high and low how to do this, everything else fails, this is simple and works like a charm! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Just to expand on @Aaron's answer, this would solve the OP's problem without altering other checkboxes on the page:

```
$('#check-all').click(function(e) {
  var checkboxes = $(e.target).closest('table').find('input:checkbox');
  var checked = $(e.target).attr('checked') === undefined;
  checkboxes.attr('checked', checked);
  checkboxes.not('#check-all').click(function() {
    $(e.target).attr('checked', false);
  });
});
```

It also has the benefit of unchecking the select all box if one of the boxes gets unchecked.