# Add select all option to simple form association collections

Tags: ruby-on-rails, html, ruby-on-rails-4, twitter-bootstrap-3, simple-form

I am using simple_form 3 and bootstrap 3 with rails 4.  I am using the following for my form

```
   <%= f.association :characteristics, collection: @holidays, 
                                       prompt: "Select Holidays", 
                                       label: false,  as: :check_boxes %>
```

I do not want to use a button as suggested here [Rails 3.1 Select All checkbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9825746/rails-3-1-select-all-checkbox), I'd prefer a checkbox in the same list as the other checkboxes.

How can I set up this "select all" checkbox?

Comment: Have you looked at this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4037537/simple-form-how-to-create-a-grouped-select-box

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

```
<%= f.association :characteristics, 
                  collection: [Holiday.new(id: 0, name: 'Select All')] + @holidays, 
                  label: false,  as: :check_boxes,
                  input_html: {data: {behaviour: 'select-all'}} %>
```

And then in js:

```
$('[data-behaviour="select-all"][value=0]').on('change', function(){
  var checked = this.checked;
  $('[data-behaviour="select-all"]').each(function(){
    $(this).prop('checked', checked);
  });
})
```

Is not an elegant solution but I think it should works

Comment: Holiday.new(id: 0, name: 'Select All')

Genius!